# Is it possible to set an Actions Submission Criteria that prevents submission if an array parameter is empty?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

If the [property] value for a submission criteria "[property] each is not null" is an empty array, the submission criteria seems to still succeed. Is there a way to have a submission criteria that prevents an Action submission if the input for an array parameter is an empty array?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what you're asking for can be achieved by doing the following:

1. open the "Security & Submission Criteria" tab on your Action type
2. add a new condition
3. Click on "based on parameter"
4. Click on the array parameter that you want to check is not empty
5. click on "Length of `name of the parameter you just selected`"
6. click on "Is not"
7. click on "Specific value" and set 0 (Note that you might have to manually write 0 in the input field even though the default value for that input field is already 0)

This will check that the lenght of your array parameter is not 0 (which means at least 1! :) )

[image: expected result screenshot]